# Change NSTableView cell value While Editing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I want to change the value being displayed in a NSTableView Cell while editing it. My requirement is the following:
Initially I entered a cell value of 234.5678978 and after editing the value is being rounded up to 0 decimal precision(that means 235). My requirement is that when I could click that cell, it should show me value unto certain decimal precision say up 5 precision, in this case 234.56790). How can I achieve this functionality.
I tried to capture the action of double click editing the cell of NSTableView:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(editingDidEnd:)
                                                 name:NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(editingDidBegin:)
                                                 name:NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(editingDidChange:)
                                                 name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)editingDidEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"text editing fisnished");
}

- (void)editingDidBegin:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"text is being edited");
}
- (void)editingDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"text was being changed");
}
```

But only `editingDidEnd` was called on tab out and the other two methods were never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a custom formatter for the edited cell in `willDisplayCell` delegate of `NSTableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        if(![[tableColumn identifier]isEqualToString:@"name"]){
            [cell setFormatter:nil];

            if (row == [tableView editedRow] && [[tableView tableColumns] indexOfObject:tableColumn] == [tableView editedColumn]) // the cell is getting edited
            {
                [(NSTextFieldCell*)cell setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
               NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                [nf setMaximumFractionDigits:5]; // Setting the precision value upto 5 decimal places
                [nf setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
                [cell setFormatter:nf];
            }
            else{
                [(NSTextFieldCell*)cell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
                //[cell setFormatter:nil];
                NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                [nf setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // setting decimal value upto 2 decimal places
                [nf setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
                [cell setFormatter:nf];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So, when a cell is edited, it will set the precision to 5 decimal places and in all other cases it will set cell formatter to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know if i'm getting correctly what you need. It seems you're dealing with a number formatting problem.
Anyway, the selectors you mention in your question *are* invoked by the AppKit but *only* if something happens in the editor view (i.e. a keystroke, for example).
Simply clicking the control (making it firstResponder) will fire nothing.
If i were you, actually, i'd rather use delegate methods (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1551/_index.html but *also* http://thegreyblog.blogspot.it/2014/06/nscontroltexteditingdelegate-methods.html
) instead of passing through the defaultNotificationCenter.
In any case, this is how i would catch *very early* the "BeginEdit" event, with the possibility of changing whatever value i want in the relevant TextField.

```
@interface YourTableView : NSTableView

@end


@implementation YourTableView

- (BOOL)validateProposedFirstResponder:(NSResponder *)responder forEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    BOOL acceptFirstResponder = [super validateProposedFirstResponder:responder forEvent:event];
    if (acceptsFirstResponder && (
        event == nil || // catches tabs
        event.type == NSLeftMouseDown)) { // catches mouse clicks) {
        [responder setStringValue:@"<YourFormattedNumber>"];
    }
    return acceptFirstResponder;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {

// Additional formatting code
    return YES;
}

@end
```

i.e. subclass your tableview and then override -validateProposedFirstResponder

Comment: `validateProposedFirstResponder` is not getting called in my NSTableView subclass.

Comment: Ensure that "refuses first responder" is unchecked in IB properties for the table view. Please note also that "validateProposedFirstResponder" is not available on targets below SDK10.7

Comment: I edited the code section in the "if" condition.
In this way its ensured that you catch only mouse clicks in your selected cell, avoiding thus interference with normal tableview superclass' behavior.
Hope it help.

Comment: My table view is programmatically created, I am not able to uncheck that property :(

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I was off in the past days. You can use: `[_yourTableView setRefusesFirstResponder:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a custom subclass of `NSFormatter`. There are two methods, `-stringForObjectValue:` and `-editingStringForObjectValue:`. The distinction is precisely what you're looking for. The first provides the value when not editing. The second provides the value when editing, for cases where it needs to be formatted differently.

Because `NSNumberFormatter` does a lot of nitty-gritty work for you, I recommend that you build your class to use an `NSNumberFormatter` or two for its implementation. That is, the methods of your class would call into an instance of `NSNumberFormatter` to do their work. You would either keep two number formatters, one for the not-editing case and the other for the editing case, or you'd use one and keep changing its configuration just before calling it, depending on which method you're implementing.